# Spring security - encoded password gives me Bad Credentials

Tags: spring, spring-security

I'm using Spring security and use an encoder to encode passwords.

So, in my Spring Security Config I have auto wired the 
`PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder()` and added it to the `DaoAuthenticationProvider`, this is my Spring Security config

```
   package it.besmart.easyparking.config;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.JdbcTokenRepositoryImpl;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.PersistentTokenRepository;
import org.springframework.security.web.servlet.support.csrf.CsrfRequestDataValueProcessor;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.RequestDataValueProcessor;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("customUserDetailsService")
    UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    CustomSuccessHandler customSuccessHandler;

    @Autowired
    CustomAuthenticationFailureHandler customAuthenticationFailureHandler;

    @Autowired
    DataSource dataSource;

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobalSecurity(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
        auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider());
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        authenticationProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
        authenticationProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        return authenticationProvider;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/", "/home", "/user/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/spots/**", "/parks/**", "/floors/**", "/lights/**", "/sensors/**", "/illumination/**",
                        "/occupation/**", "/movement/**", "/map/**", "/include/**")
                .access("hasRole('USER') or hasRole('ADMIN') or hasRole('PARK')").antMatchers("/admin/**")
                .access("hasRole('ADMIN') and hasRole('PARK')").antMatchers("/updatePassword")
                .hasAuthority("CHANGE_PASSWORD_PRIVILEGE").

                and().formLogin().loginPage("/login").successHandler(customSuccessHandler)
                .failureHandler(customAuthenticationFailureHandler).usernameParameter("email")
                .passwordParameter("password").and().rememberMe().rememberMeParameter("remember-me")
                .tokenRepository(persistentTokenRepository()).tokenValiditySeconds(86400).and().csrf().and()
                .exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/Access_Denied");

    }

    @Bean
    public PersistentTokenRepository persistentTokenRepository() {
        JdbcTokenRepositoryImpl tokenRepositoryImpl = new JdbcTokenRepositoryImpl();
        tokenRepositoryImpl.setDataSource(dataSource);
        return tokenRepositoryImpl;
    }

    @Bean
    public RequestDataValueProcessor requestDataValueProcessor() {
        return new CsrfRequestDataValueProcessor();
    }

}
```

When i pass data from my DTO to the Model I simply do the following

```
user.setPassword(passwordEncoder.encode(accountDTO.getPassword()));
```

And in my DB i see the encoded password, for instance something like *$2a$10$vVCWjKltOiYO0nPYT1qYI.z4TSk2QJqViDOqRfmoB6BAgldF4vAmm*

But when i try to login i'm getting

```
org.springframework.security.authentication.BadCredentialsException: Bad credentials
```

When i see logs, i find this

```
o.s.s.c.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder     : Encoded password does not look like BCrypt
```

My password field in the DB is varchar(100) so i think there is enough space to store it...
If i change the encoded password in the DB with a decoded one, i can login...

this is my CustoUserDetailsService

```
@Service("customUserDetailsService")
public class CustomUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    UserRepository repository;

    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CustomUserDetailsService.class);

    @Override
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String email) throws UsernameNotFoundException {

        boolean accountNonExpired = true;
        boolean credentialsNonExpired = true;
        boolean accountNonLocked = true;
        try {
            User user = repository.findByEmail(email);
            if (user == null) {
                throw new UsernameNotFoundException("No user found with username: " + email);
            }
            logger.debug("user: " + user.toString());
            return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(user.getEmail(),

                    user.getPassword(), user.isEnabled(), accountNonExpired, credentialsNonExpired, accountNonLocked,
                    getAuthorities(user));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);

        }
    }

    private List<GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities(User user) {
        List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();

        authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_" + user.getUserProfile().getType()));

        // System.out.print("authorities :"+authorities);
        return authorities;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The exception has been thrown by `UserDetailsService.loadUserByUsername()` method at the `return` position because of the wrong instantiated `User` object that hasn't received the encoded password in the corresponding field.

The correct code would look like this:

```
...

public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) 
                                      throws UsernameNotFoundException {
  
    UserEntity user = userRepository.findByUsername(username);

    if (user == null)
       throw new UsernameNotFoundException("Bad credentials");

    return new User(
        user.getUsername(), 
        user.getPassword(), // shall to be the already BCrypt-encrypted password
        getAuthorities());
}
```

The `org.springframework.security.authentication.BadCredentialsException: Bad credentials` will be thrown once the `user.getPassword()` isn't well formed BCrypt hashsum.

The password encoder may be registered like this:

```
@Autowired
public BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
}

protected void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
            
     auth
          .userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
          .passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder);
}
```

That's how it works.

Comment: Thanks, i added mi CustomUserDetailsService and it looks like yours, the problem is the password because if i add manually a non-encoded pass in the DB, i can login

Comment: @besmart, seems like yours `passwordEncoder` is not visible by Spring Security, checkout the update

Comment: I really don't know why this happens... the `passwordEncoder` bean is correctly seen by spring, i can log it in my Spring configuration... logs say me that `DaoAuthenticationProvider - Authentication failed: password does not match stored value`

Comment: Throw out the `authenticationProvider()` at all and register the `passwordEncoder` inside the `configureGlobalSecurity()` just like it's done with `userDetailsService` despite it still visible by the framework

Comment: there is no `passwordEncoder` for `AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth`

Comment: @besmart, I meant 'auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder)', sorry:(

Comment: thank you so much, you saved my day! Or, better, my week!!

Comment: ///Happy end:))

Answer (score 1):

The PasswordEncoder should be set like this:

```
@Bean
public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
  return PasswordEncoderFactories.createDelegatingPasswordEncoder();
}
```

Also you need to use the passwordEncoder for the users and clients.

You can check this repository https://github.com/dzinot/spring-boot-2-oauth2-authorization-jwt

It uses **Spring Boot 2**, JWT tokens and the Users and Clients are stored in the database.