# Spring boot: i keep getting org.springframework.security.authentication.BadCredentialsException: Bad credentials and i dont know why

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I am trying to configure my SpringBoot app with JWT, and every time I try to do an authentication using my JWTAuthenticationFilter.class, I get a bad credential exception. I feel the whole problem is as a result of Bycrpt, because going by this [link,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43007763/spring-security-encoded-password-gives-me-bad-credentials) the user complained about same issue. but when i implemented his code it didn't work for me.

below is my spring security configurer class:

```
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
```

//@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class JwtSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

```
private final CustomerDetailsService customerDetailsService;

@Autowired
private JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint unauthorizedHandler;

@Autowired
public JwtSecurityConfiguration(CustomerDetailsService customerDetailsService) {
    this.customerDetailsService = customerDetailsService;
}

@Autowired
public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder(){
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
}

@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    web.ignoring().antMatchers("/resources/**");
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/welcome/login").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("**/rest/**").authenticated()
            .and()
            .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedHandler)
            .and()
            .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);

    http.addFilterBefore(new JWTAuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager(), 
            (BCryptPasswordEncoder) passwordEncoder()), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    http.addFilter(new JWTAuthorizationFilter(authenticationManager(),customerDetailsService));
    http
            .headers()
            .frameOptions().sameOrigin()
            .cacheControl();
}
```

}

and this is the JWTAuthenticationFiler class :

```
public class JWTAuthenticationFilter extends UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter {

private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

@Autowired
private BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;

public JWTAuthenticationFilter(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager, BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder) {
    this.authenticationManager = authenticationManager;
    this.bCryptPasswordEncoder = bCryptPasswordEncoder;
}

@Override
public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws AuthenticationException {
    try {
        User user = new ObjectMapper().readValue(request.getInputStream(), User.class);
        user.setPassword(bCryptPasswordEncoder.encode(user.getPassword()));
        return authenticationManager.authenticate(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user.getUserName(), user.getPassword()));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}

@Override
protected void successfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain, Authentication authResult) throws IOException, ServletException {
    ZonedDateTime expirationTimeUTC = ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneOffset.UTC).plus(EXPIRATION_TIME, ChronoUnit.MILLIS);
    String token = Jwts.builder().setSubject(((User)authResult.getPrincipal()).getUserName())
            .setExpiration(Date.from(expirationTimeUTC.toInstant()))
            .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.ES256, SECRET)
            .compact();
    response.getWriter().write(token);
    response.addHeader(HEADER, TOKEN_PREFIX + token);
}

@Override
protected void unsuccessfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException failed) throws IOException, ServletException {
    super.unsuccessfulAuthentication(request, response, failed);
    response.getWriter().write(failed.getMessage());
}
```

}

and finally this is my customerdetailservice class:

```
@Component
public class CustomerDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

@Autowired
DefaultUserDAOService defaultUserDAOService;

@Override
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
    User user = defaultUserDAOService.getByUsername(username);
    if (user == null) {
        throw new UsernameNotFoundException(String.format("No user found with username '%s'.", username));
    } else {
        return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(user.getUserName(), user.getPassword(),
                AuthorityUtils.createAuthorityList("ROLE_USER"));
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

When you added new user, did you do:

user.setPassword(bCryptPasswordEncoder.encode(user.getPassword()));

before you save it in your DB? Spring will not do that for you, you have to do it your self. and make sure you use the same algorithm and salts (if have)

check your DB to see what's the password really saved.

Hope this may help you.

Comment: yes, i did that. i removed Brypt totally, but i am still getting the error

Comment: Maybe you can enable the spring security log level on debug, then check the log info, see on which interceptor stop the process and return a bad credential. make sure the problem happened on your own interceptor first. then I noticed you enabled the EnableGlobalMethodSecurity, disable it first. The code you provide is not enough for debugging, but I hope my suggestion may help to to find the reason.

Comment: Autowired
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder(){

        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    } also change the autowired to Bean